# Wrapping / Unwrapping Universally Quantified Types

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type

I have imported a data type, `X`, defined as

```
data X a = X a
```

Locally, I have defined a universally quantified data type, `Y`

```
type Y = forall a. X a
```

Now I need to define two functions, `toY` and `fromY`. For `fromY`, this definition works fine:

```
fromY :: Y -> X a
fromY a = a
```

but if I try the same thing for `toY`, I get an error

```
Couldn't match type 'a' with 'a0'
'a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for 'toY :: X a -> y'
'a0' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for 'toY :: X a -> X a0'
Expected type: X a0
Actual type: X a
```

If I understand correctly, the type signature for `toY` is expanding to `forall a. X a -> (forall a0. X a0)` because `Y` is defined as a synonym, rather than a newtype, and so the two `a`s in the definitions don't match up.

But if this is the case, then why does `fromY` type-check successfully? And is there any way around this problem other than using `unsafeCoerce`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Remark:

This is more like a comment but I could not really put it there as it would have been unreadable; please forgive me this one time.

---

Aside from what dfeuer already told you, you might see (when you use his answer) that `toY` is now really easy to do but you might have trouble defining `fromY` – because you basically lose the type-information, so this **will not work**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module ExTypes where

data X a = X a

data Y where
  Y :: X a -> Y

fromY :: Y -> X a
fromY (Y a) = a
```

as here you have two different `a`s – one from the constructor `Y` and one from `X a` – indeed if you strip the definition and try to compile: `fromY (Y a) = a` the compiler will tell you that the *type `a` escapes*:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t' with actual type `X a'
  because type variable `a' would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  a pattern with constructor
    Y :: forall a. X a -> Y,
  in an equation for `fromY'
```

I think the only thing you will have left now will be something like this:

```
useY :: (forall a . X a -> b) -> Y -> b
useY f (Y x) = f x
```

but this might prove not to be too useful.

The thing is that you normally should constrain the `forall a` there a bit more (with type-classes) to get any meaningful behavior – but of course I cannot help here.

This [wiki article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) might be interesting for you on the details.

Comment: Your remark took me a while. Don't you mean "I could not really __put__ it there"? That being said you can always edit other answers to add more information, or provide a link to a gist/similar external resources in a comment if you think that's more appropriate.

Comment: yes sorry `put` (one moment) - and yeah I could edit dfeuers answer (and I've done so on occasion) but in this case I kindof hoped to get some rep as well (yeah I know, I already feel ashamed) ^^

Comment: Constrain the forall, or stick more than one thing in the box, that will match each other.

Comment: **thanks for the edit** ... I should not answer questions before my first cup of coffee ... seems my fingers are faster than my brain (and yes the english was horrible)

Answer (score 7):

You claim to define an existential type, but you do not.

```
type Y = forall a. X a
```

defines a universally quantified type. For something to have type `Y`, it must have type `X a` for *every* `a`. To make an existentially quantified type, you always need to use `data`, and I find the GADT syntax easier to understand than the traditional existential one.

```
data Y where
  Y :: forall a . X a -> Y
```

The `forall` there is actually optional, but I think clarifies things.

I'm too sleepy right now to work out your other questions, but I'll try again tomorrow if no one else does.